# Сброс переменных

Tags: php

> *При сбросе ссылки, просто разрывается связь имени и содержимого переменной.
> Это не означает, что содержимое
> переменной будет разрушено. Например:*

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b =& $a;
unset($a); 
?>
```

> *Этот код не сбросит $b, а только $a.*

Нашел это в мануале. И как это понимать? Содержимое не будет разрушено, пока есть ещё ссылки на него? А когда последняя ссылка разрушится, то содержимое освободится?

Comment: Объект не удаляется из памяти автоматической сборкой мусора ровно до тех пор, пока на него указывает хотя бы одна ссылка. Так что ответ на ваши вопросы - да.

Comment: Правильно поняли. Только не надо забывать про циклические ссылки (т.е. a -> b -> c -> b).

Если даже на b не ссылается ни одна переменная, кроме a (но при этом ссылается какой-то объект c, на который в свою очередь ссылается объект b), то удаление a не приведет к удалению b и с. Для этого надо вызывать сборщик мусора - он должен такие ситуации обрабатывать, как следует.

Хотя че-то слышал, что в новых версиях PHP вроде как это должно нормально обрабатываться, но точно сказать не могу - сам пока не сталкивался, поэтому не уверен.

И вопрос на засыпку: $a = null; Что будет в $b? )))

Comment: @BOPOH, ответ на последний вопрос проверил на всякий, а то что-то засомневался), наверное, потому что не знаю, как unset удаляет переменные. Кстати, а чтобы вы могли сказать по этому поводу [ссылка][1]?


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/358049/php-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC